# Differentiate power modes when plugged-in vs on-battery

Tags: 22.04, suspend, power-management, battery

The native power settings on Ubuntu 22.04.3 are as follow:

[image]

Is there an easy and native way to differentiate those settings between a plugged-in mode or an on-battery mode (and especially the time when the screen goes to sleep, because my screen goes black even when plugged)?

Answer (score 0):

`power-profiles-daemon`, the backend of the Gnome Power Mode GUI, doesn't support changing profiles depending on power source. As an alternative you may install `TLP` (I'm the author) and configure it to replicate ppd's behaviour. You *will* lose the GUI however.

https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/ppd.html#how-can-i-use-tlp-to-achieve-the-same-effect-as-power-profiles-daemon